Does Rev 22:6 and Rev 22:16 prove in black and white that Jesus is God?
I was having a Bible discussion with my Christian brother this morning and we happened to bump into this verse in Revelation chapter 22 that actually confirms Jesus is God indirectly. Our subject is on the identity of the sender who sent his angel to show John this vision. If we look at the statement made by the angel to John and the corresponding affirmative statement made by Jesus then we can infer that the sender who is the God of the prophets is actually Jesus Christ.
Revelation 22:6

And the Lord, the God of the spirits of the prophets, has sent his angel to show his servants what must soon take place

Revelation 22:16

I, Jesus, have sent my angel to testify to you about these things for the churches

So from both verses it can be concluded that the sender is God aka Jesus Christ, is this the case?

I cannot believe Jesus left the glory he shared with the Most High to come and die for people like me who did not deserve that love, I am humbled.

This question is in need of scoping to a specific denomination. As written it is a truth question and opinion based

@Lesly, it humbles me that such a powerful entity like Jesus can take on a human form to live with us to teach us the way onto God , I am humbled.

Amen to that :-)

Yes, when the entirety of Scripture is brought to bear.
God sent the Angel.  Jesus sent the angel  Both refer to the angel in the possessive.  The Lord, who is the God of the spirit of the prophets (which is unequivocally referring to YHWH), sent his angel and Jesus sent his angel.
Both refer to one angel and one instance of one sending.
In similar fashion, God the Father sends the Holy Spirit (John 14:26) and Jesus sends the Holy Spirit (John 16:7).
In similar fashion, the Spirit of God in a believer is also the Spirit of Christ:

But ye are not in the flesh, but in the Spirit, if so be that the Spirit of God dwell in you. Now if any man have not the Spirit of Christ, he is none of his. And if Christ be in you, the body is dead because of sin; but the Spirit is life because of righteousness. - Romans 8:9-10

There is a differentiation in role between Father and Son which is often misunderstood as a differentiation in being or essence.
